# How to read an array inside another array in an " Json object" -> Jade/PUG.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, oop, pug

I'm trying to "create" a template using "Json" in Pug, but there is a point where I need to put much Information. But the problem for me becomes where I need to read an element deeply inside.

```
-
  var SuperSlidersInfo = {
      'numero': '4',
      'sectionName': 'Dignidad',
      'video': true,
      'youtube': [
        'idVideo',
        'idVideo2',
        ],
      'notes':[
        ['prueba1', 'prueba2'],
        ['segundo1', 'segundo2', 'segundo3'],
      ],
      'img': [
        'NombreImagen',
        'NombreImagen2',
        ],
      'extension': 'jpg',
      'titulo': [
        'Titulo',
        ],
      'parrafo': [
        'Texto',
      ]}
+SuperSlidersPug(SuperSlidersInfo)
```

```
mixin SuperSlidersPug(SuperSlidersInfo)
 .container-pc
    .container-sliderAutomatico.no-phone
      div(id=`sliderAutomatico${SuperSlidersInfo.numero}` class= SuperSlidersInfo.video ? "dosVideos-container" : "otraCosa").sliderAutomatico
        each imgName, index in SuperSlidersInfo.img
          //- div(class= SuperSlidersInfo.video ? "dosVideos").sliderAutomatico__section
          div(class= SuperSlidersInfo.video ? "dosVideos" : "otraCosa").sliderAutomatico__section
            .swiper-content
              if SuperSlidersInfo.video
                .section_videoContainer
                  a(href=`#video${SuperSlidersInfo.sectionName}${index}`).section_videoThumbnail--Container
                    img(src=`${imgURL}${SuperSlidersInfo.sectionName}${index + 1}.${SuperSlidersInfo.extension}`, alt="")
                  h3.swiper-content_titulo= `${SuperSlidersInfo.titulo[index]}`
                  .section_video--notes
                    //- -----------------
                    //- Problem
                    //- -----------------
                    //- the "a" below works, but I need to "create" and each, or for, or any loop for to put all the elements in that especific array. 
                    //- a(href=`${SuperSlidersInfo.notes[index]}`).section_video--note
                    
                    //- The "each" below it suppose to works. But when I put the "[index]" it brokes..
                    each note, noteIndex in SuperSlidersInfo.notes[index]
                      a(href=`${note}`).section_video--note
```

For general elements it works well. But when I need to read the "notes". It's impossible por me.

But when I put `each note, noteIndex in SuperSlidersInfo.notes[index]` everything is broken...

So I need to read the "elements" that "note" has in its array...

```
//- Works well
each note, noteIndex in SuperSlidersInfo.notes
//- Or...
each note, noteIndex in SuperSlidersInfo.notes[0]

//- But if I put this It's Broke (And I thought that could works well)
each note, noteIndex in SuperSlidersInfo.notes[index]
```

the `index` is from the `each` that exist almost at top of the code.

And How I said, it's a "template" so sometime I don't know how many "items" could exist. So I need to use an `each` for all the elements that could exist...

Answer (score 0):

its actually pretty easy.What you are referring is an two dimensional array
(i.e.,) Arr[i][j]

so to access the deeper element in the notes array write

SuperSlidersInfo.notes[i][j];

for example,
to access segundo1 write

SuperSlidersInfo.notes[1][0];

Edit:
you could use a nested for loop,In that case you need not know the no of items beforehand,
code:

```js
let obj = {
    'numero': '4',
    'sectionName': 'Dignidad',
    'video': true,
    'youtube': [
      'idVideo',
      'idVideo2',
      ],
    'notes':[
      ['prueba1', 'prueba2'],
      ['segundo1', 'segundo2', 'segundo3'],
    ],
    'img': [
      'NombreImagen',
      'NombreImagen2',
      ],
    'extension': 'jpg',
    'titulo': [
      'Titulo',
      ],
    'parrafo': [
      'Texto',
    ]}

    let notes = obj.notes;
for(let i =0;i<notes.length;i++){
      let inner = notes[i];
  for(let j=0;j<inner.length;j++){
    console.log(inner[j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok yes, but I have to do this "manually". And the idea is "automatically". So for that I suposte to put an `index` in the first `[]`... `[index]`... But Pug doesn't let me do this... Because, in another project could exist more "notes". or maybe less... So I don't know. And the idea is create this "automatically".